# calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I'm running Kubernetes 1.13.2, setup using kubeadm and struggling with getting calico 3.5 up and running.  The cluster is run on top of KVM.

Setup:

1. `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.255.253.20 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`
2. modified `calico.yaml` file to include:

   ```
       - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
         value: "interface=ens.*"
   ```
3. applied `rbac.yaml`, `etcd.yaml`, `calico.yaml`

Output from `kubectl describe pods`:

```
Events:
Type     Reason     Age                     From                    Message
----     ------     ----                    ----                    -------
Normal   Scheduled  23m                     default-scheduler       Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-node-hjwrc to k8s-master-01
Normal   Pulling    23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  pulling image "quay.io/calico/cni:v3.5.0"
Normal   Pulled     23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/calico/cni:v3.5.0"
Normal   Created    23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Created container
Normal   Started    23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Started container
Normal   Pulling    23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  pulling image "quay.io/calico/node:v3.5.0"
Normal   Pulled     23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/calico/node:v3.5.0"
Warning  Unhealthy  23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: felix is not ready: Get http://localhost:9099/readiness: dial tcp [::1]:9099: connect: connection refused
Warning  Unhealthy  23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Liveness probe failed: Get http://localhost:9099/liveness: dial tcp [::1]:9099: connect: connection refused
Normal   Created    23m (x2 over 23m)       kubelet, k8s-master-01  Created container
Normal   Started    23m (x2 over 23m)       kubelet, k8s-master-01  Started container
Normal   Pulled     23m                     kubelet, k8s-master-01  Container image "quay.io/calico/node:v3.5.0" already present on machine
Warning  Unhealthy  3m32s (x23 over 7m12s)  kubelet, k8s-master-01  Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with 10.255.253.22
```

Output from `calicoctl node status`:

```
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |  INFO   |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| 10.255.253.22 | node-to-node mesh | start | 16:24:44 | Passive |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

Output from `ETCD_ENDPOINTS=http://localhost:6666 calicoctl get nodes -o yaml`:

```
    apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
items:
- apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: Node
metadata:
    annotations:
    projectcalico.org/kube-labels: '{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/hostname":"k8s-master-01","node-role.kubernetes.io/master":""}'
    creationTimestamp: 2019-01-31T16:08:56Z
    labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-master-01
    node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
    name: k8s-master-01
    resourceVersion: "28"
    uid: 82fee4dc-2572-11e9-8ab7-5254002c725d
spec:
    bgp:
    ipv4Address: 10.255.253.20/24
    ipv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 192.168.151.128
    orchRefs:
    - nodeName: k8s-master-01
    orchestrator: k8s
- apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: Node
metadata:
    annotations:
    projectcalico.org/kube-labels: '{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/hostname":"k8s-worker-01"}'
    creationTimestamp: 2019-01-31T16:24:44Z
    labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-worker-01
    name: k8s-worker-01
    resourceVersion: "170"
    uid: b7c2c5a6-2574-11e9-aaa4-5254007d5f6a
spec:
    bgp:
    ipv4Address: 10.255.253.22/24
    ipv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 192.168.36.192
    orchRefs:
    - nodeName: k8s-worker-01
    orchestrator: k8s
kind: NodeList
metadata:
resourceVersion: "395"
```

Output from `ETCD_ENDPOINTS=http://localhost:6666 calicoctl get bgppeers`:

```
NAME   PEERIP   NODE   ASN
```

Ouput from `kubectl logs`:

```
2019-01-31 17:01:20.519 [INFO][48] int_dataplane.go 751: Applying dataplane updates
2019-01-31 17:01:20.519 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 223: Asked to resync with the dataplane on next update. family="inet"
2019-01-31 17:01:20.519 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 254: Resyncing ipsets with dataplane. family="inet"
2019-01-31 17:01:20.523 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 304: Finished resync family="inet" numInconsistenciesFound=0 resyncDuration=3.675284ms
2019-01-31 17:01:20.523 [INFO][48] int_dataplane.go 765: Finished applying updates to dataplane. msecToApply=4.124166000000001
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 36329)
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 52383)
2019-01-31 17:01:23.182 [INFO][48] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 39661)
2019-01-31 17:01:25.433 [INFO][48] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 57359)
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 47151)
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 39243)
2019-01-31 17:01:30.943 [INFO][48] int_dataplane.go 751: Applying dataplane updates
2019-01-31 17:01:30.943 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 223: Asked to resync with the dataplane on next update. family="inet"
2019-01-31 17:01:30.943 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 254: Resyncing ipsets with dataplane. family="inet"
2019-01-31 17:01:30.945 [INFO][48] ipsets.go 304: Finished resync family="inet" numInconsistenciesFound=0 resyncDuration=2.369997ms
2019-01-31 17:01:30.946 [INFO][48] int_dataplane.go 765: Finished applying updates to dataplane. msecToApply=2.8165820000000004
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.255.253.14 (port 60641)
2019-01-31 17:01:33.190 [INFO][48] health.go 150: Overall health summary=&health.HealthReport{Live:true, Ready:true}
```

Note: the above unknown address (10.255.253.14) is the IP under `br0` on the KVM host, not too sure why it's made an appearance.

Comment: Can you list your network interfaces?

Comment: @phone_melter : Can you share your fix ?

Comment: For me it was just the firewall.. This command solved `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the solution :

The first preference of ifconfig(in my case) through that it will try to connect to the worker-nodes which is not the right ip.

Solution:Change the calico.yaml file to override that ip to etho-ip by using the following steps.

Need to open port [Calico networking (BGP) - TCP 179](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements)

```
 # Specify interface
            - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
              value: "interface=eth1"
```

## calico.yaml

```
---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-config.yaml
# This ConfigMap is used to configure a self-hosted Calico installation.
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: calico-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  # Typha is disabled.
  typha_service_name: "none"
  # Configure the backend to use.
  calico_backend: "bird"

  # Configure the MTU to use
  veth_mtu: "1440"

  # The CNI network configuration to install on each node.  The special
  # values in this config will be automatically populated.
  cni_network_config: |-
    {
      "name": "k8s-pod-network",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "calico",
          "log_level": "info",
          "datastore_type": "kubernetes",
          "nodename": "__KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME__",
          "mtu": __CNI_MTU__,
          "ipam": {
              "type": "calico-ipam"
          },
          "policy": {
              "type": "k8s"
          },
          "kubernetes": {
              "kubeconfig": "__KUBECONFIG_FILEPATH__"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "snat": true,
          "capabilities": {"portMappings": true}
        }
      ]
    }

---
# Source: calico/templates/kdd-crds.yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
   name: felixconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: FelixConfiguration
    plural: felixconfigurations
    singular: felixconfiguration
---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMBlock
    plural: ipamblocks
    singular: ipamblock

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: blockaffinities.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: BlockAffinity
    plural: blockaffinities
    singular: blockaffinity

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamhandles.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMHandle
    plural: ipamhandles
    singular: ipamhandle

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMConfig
    plural: ipamconfigs
    singular: ipamconfig

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: bgppeers.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: BGPPeer
    plural: bgppeers
    singular: bgppeer

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: bgpconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: BGPConfiguration
    plural: bgpconfigurations
    singular: bgpconfiguration

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ippools.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPPool
    plural: ippools
    singular: ippool

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: hostendpoints.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: HostEndpoint
    plural: hostendpoints
    singular: hostendpoint

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: ClusterInformation
    plural: clusterinformations
    singular: clusterinformation

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: globalnetworkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    plural: globalnetworkpolicies
    singular: globalnetworkpolicy

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: globalnetworksets.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: GlobalNetworkSet
    plural: globalnetworksets
    singular: globalnetworkset

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: NetworkPolicy
    plural: networkpolicies
    singular: networkpolicy

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: networksets.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: NetworkSet
    plural: networksets
    singular: networkset
---
# Source: calico/templates/rbac.yaml

# Include a clusterrole for the kube-controllers component,
# and bind it to the calico-kube-controllers serviceaccount.
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
rules:
  # Nodes are watched to monitor for deletions.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - watch
      - list
      - get
  # Pods are queried to check for existence.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - get
  # IPAM resources are manipulated when nodes are deleted.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ippools
    verbs:
      - list
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
      - ipamblocks
      - ipamhandles
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - update
      - delete
  # Needs access to update clusterinformations.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - clusterinformations
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - update
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: calico-kube-controllers
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
---
# Include a clusterrole for the calico-node DaemonSet,
# and bind it to the calico-node serviceaccount.
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
rules:
  # The CNI plugin needs to get pods, nodes, and namespaces.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
      - nodes
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - endpoints
      - services
    verbs:
      # Used to discover service IPs for advertisement.
      - watch
      - list
      # Used to discover Typhas.
      - get
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes/status
    verbs:
      # Needed for clearing NodeNetworkUnavailable flag.
      - patch
      # Calico stores some configuration information in node annotations.
      - update
  # Watch for changes to Kubernetes NetworkPolicies.
  - apiGroups: ["networking.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - networkpolicies
    verbs:
      - watch
      - list
  # Used by Calico for policy information.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
      - namespaces
      - serviceaccounts
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  # The CNI plugin patches pods/status.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods/status
    verbs:
      - patch
  # Calico monitors various CRDs for config.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - globalfelixconfigs
      - felixconfigurations
      - bgppeers
      - globalbgpconfigs
      - bgpconfigurations
      - ippools
      - ipamblocks
      - globalnetworkpolicies
      - globalnetworksets
      - networkpolicies
      - networksets
      - clusterinformations
      - hostendpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  # Calico must create and update some CRDs on startup.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ippools
      - felixconfigurations
      - clusterinformations
    verbs:
      - create
      - update
  # Calico stores some configuration information on the node.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  # These permissions are only requried for upgrade from v2.6, and can
  # be removed after upgrade or on fresh installations.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - bgpconfigurations
      - bgppeers
    verbs:
      - create
      - update
  # These permissions are required for Calico CNI to perform IPAM allocations.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
      - ipamblocks
      - ipamhandles
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - update
      - delete
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ipamconfigs
    verbs:
      - get
  # Block affinities must also be watchable by confd for route aggregation.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
    verbs:
      - watch
  # The Calico IPAM migration needs to get daemonsets. These permissions can be
  # removed if not upgrading from an installation using host-local IPAM.
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - daemonsets
    verbs:
      - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: calico-node
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: calico-node
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-node.yaml
# This manifest installs the calico-node container, as well
# as the CNI plugins and network config on
# each master and worker node in a Kubernetes cluster.
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-node
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-node
      annotations:
        # This, along with the CriticalAddonsOnly toleration below,
        # marks the pod as a critical add-on, ensuring it gets
        # priority scheduling and that its resources are reserved
        # if it ever gets evicted.
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      hostNetwork: true
      tolerations:
        # Make sure calico-node gets scheduled on all nodes.
        - effect: NoSchedule
          operator: Exists
        # Mark the pod as a critical add-on for rescheduling.
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
        - effect: NoExecute
          operator: Exists
      serviceAccountName: calico-node
      # Minimize downtime during a rolling upgrade or deletion; tell Kubernetes to do a "force
      # deletion": https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods.
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      priorityClassName: system-node-critical
      initContainers:
        # This container performs upgrade from host-local IPAM to calico-ipam.
        # It can be deleted if this is a fresh installation, or if you have already
        # upgraded to use calico-ipam.
        - name: upgrade-ipam
          image: calico/cni:v3.8.2
          command: ["/opt/cni/bin/calico-ipam", "-upgrade"]
          env:
            - name: KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: calico_backend
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/cni/networks
              name: host-local-net-dir
            - mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
              name: cni-bin-dir
        # This container installs the CNI binaries
        # and CNI network config file on each node.
        - name: install-cni
          image: calico/cni:v3.8.2
          command: ["/install-cni.sh"]
          env:
            # Name of the CNI config file to create.
            - name: CNI_CONF_NAME
              value: "10-calico.conflist"
            # The CNI network config to install on each node.
            - name: CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: cni_network_config
            # Set the hostname based on the k8s node name.
            - name: KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            # CNI MTU Config variable
            - name: CNI_MTU
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: veth_mtu
            # Prevents the container from sleeping forever.
            - name: SLEEP
              value: "false"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
              name: cni-bin-dir
            - mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d
              name: cni-net-dir
        # Adds a Flex Volume Driver that creates a per-pod Unix Domain Socket to allow Dikastes
        # to communicate with Felix over the Policy Sync API.
        - name: flexvol-driver
          image: calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.8.2
          volumeMounts:
          - name: flexvol-driver-host
            mountPath: /host/driver
      containers:
        # Runs calico-node container on each Kubernetes node.  This
        # container programs network policy and routes on each
        # host.
        - name: calico-node
          image: calico/node:v3.8.2
          env:
            # Use Kubernetes API as the backing datastore.
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: "kubernetes"
            # Wait for the datastore.
            - name: WAIT_FOR_DATASTORE
              value: "true"
            # Set based on the k8s node name.
            - name: NODENAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            # Choose the backend to use.
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: calico_backend
            # Cluster type to identify the deployment type
            - name: CLUSTER_TYPE
              value: "k8s,bgp"
            # Specify interface
            - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
              value: "interface=eth1"
            # Auto-detect the BGP IP address.
            - name: IP
              value: "autodetect"
            # Enable IPIP
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_IPIP
              value: "Always"
            # Set MTU for tunnel device used if ipip is enabled
            - name: FELIX_IPINIPMTU
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: veth_mtu
            # The default IPv4 pool to create on startup if none exists. Pod IPs will be
            # chosen from this range. Changing this value after installation will have
            # no effect. This should fall within `--cluster-cidr`.
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
              value: "192.168.0.0/16"
            # Disable file logging so `kubectl logs` works.
            - name: CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING
              value: "true"
            # Set Felix endpoint to host default action to ACCEPT.
            - name: FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION
              value: "ACCEPT"
            # Disable IPv6 on Kubernetes.
            - name: FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT
              value: "false"
            # Set Felix logging to "info"
            - name: FELIX_LOGSEVERITYSCREEN
              value: "info"
            - name: FELIX_HEALTHENABLED
              value: "true"
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /liveness
              port: 9099
              host: localhost
            periodSeconds: 10
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/calico-node
              - -bird-ready
              - -felix-ready
            periodSeconds: 10
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /lib/modules
              name: lib-modules
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /run/xtables.lock
              name: xtables-lock
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /var/run/calico
              name: var-run-calico
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /var/lib/calico
              name: var-lib-calico
              readOnly: false
            - name: policysync
              mountPath: /var/run/nodeagent
      volumes:
        # Used by calico-node.
        - name: lib-modules
          hostPath:
            path: /lib/modules
        - name: var-run-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/calico
        - name: var-lib-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/calico
        - name: xtables-lock
          hostPath:
            path: /run/xtables.lock
            type: FileOrCreate
        # Used to install CNI.
        - name: cni-bin-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /opt/cni/bin
        - name: cni-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        # Mount in the directory for host-local IPAM allocations. This is
        # used when upgrading from host-local to calico-ipam, and can be removed
        # if not using the upgrade-ipam init container.
        - name: host-local-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/cni/networks
        # Used to create per-pod Unix Domain Sockets
        - name: policysync
          hostPath:
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
            path: /var/run/nodeagent
        # Used to install Flex Volume Driver
        - name: flexvol-driver-host
          hostPath:
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
            path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/nodeagent~uds
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-kube-controllers.yaml

# See https://github.com/projectcalico/kube-controllers
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
spec:
  # The controllers can only have a single active instance.
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: calico-kube-controllers
      namespace: kube-system
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      tolerations:
        # Mark the pod as a critical add-on for rescheduling.
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: calico-kube-controllers
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      containers:
        - name: calico-kube-controllers
          image: calico/kube-controllers:v3.8.2
          env:
            # Choose which controllers to run.
            - name: ENABLED_CONTROLLERS
              value: node
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: kubernetes
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /usr/bin/check-status
              - -r

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-etcd-secrets.yaml

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-typha.yaml

---
# Source: calico/templates/configure-canal.yaml
```

Comment: Great ! Many thanks @Avinash Tripathy. For me, I added IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD and  using: httpGet:
              path: /liveness
              port: 9099
              host: localhost

Comment: Your answer really helpful. Here is the command which allow you to edit the file - `kubectl edit DaemonSet calico-node -n kube-system`

Answer (score 11):

As an addition to this it can also be set using the following kubectl command;

kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system 
IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=eth1

Comment: Thank you. This worked. `kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=ens\*`

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the docker service on that node, and the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

the best solution :

1. Make sure that TCP port 179 is open [https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements](https://Calico%20networking%20(BGP)%20-%20TCP%20179)

   firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=179/tcp --permanent

   firewall-cmd --reload

2. Then put this command

```
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=eth.*
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just uncommented - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR value: "192.168.0.0/16"
or you can change the CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR value to the same range as kubernete's --pod-network-cidr value.

Answer (score -1):

### Disable Firewall

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service  
sudo systemctl disable firewalld.service
```

#### And restart your pod

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> -n <name-ns>
```

#### check

```
watch kubectl get pod -n <names-ns>
```

Answer (score -7):

This is normal behavior. There must be some not working node in normal status. You can use `kubectl get node --all-namespaces` to check it. After you recover the problem node, the problem will do away.