# Pods can't ping each other in a kubernetes cluster spawned over nodes from two different subnets

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, calico, kubespray

I am trying to bring up an on-prem k8 cluster using kubespray with 3 master and 5 worker nodes. The node IPs are from 2 different subnets.

Ansible inventory:

```
hosts:
saba-k8-vm-m1:
  ansible_host: 192.168.100.1
  ip: 192.168.100.1
  access_ip: 192.168.100.1
saba-k8-vm-m2:
  ansible_host: 192.168.100.2
  ip: 192.168.100.2
  access_ip: 192.168.100.2
saba-k8-vm-m3:
  ansible_host: 192.168.200.1
  ip: 192.168.200.1
  access_ip: 192.168.200.1
saba-k8-vm-w1:
  ansible_host: 192.168.100.3
  ip: 192.168.100.3
  access_ip: 192.168.100.3
saba-k8-vm-w2:
  ansible_host: 192.168.100.4
  ip: 192.168.100.4
  access_ip: 192.168.100.4
saba-k8-vm-w3:
  ansible_host: 192.168.100.5
  ip: 192.168.100.5
  access_ip: 192.168.100.5
saba-k8-vm-w4:
  ansible_host: 192.168.200.2
  ip: 192.168.200.2
  access_ip: 192.168.200.2
saba-k8-vm-w5:
  ansible_host: 192.168.200.3
  ip: 192.168.200.3
  access_ip: 192.168.200.3


children:
    kube-master:
      hosts:
        saba-k8-vm-m1:
        saba-k8-vm-m2:
        saba-k8-vm-m3:
    kube-node:
      hosts:
        saba-k8-vm-w1:
        saba-k8-vm-w2:
        saba-k8-vm-w3:
        saba-k8-vm-w4:
        saba-k8-vm-w5:
```

I spawned dnsutils next - `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml`
This is on w1 worker. It is able to lookup a svc name (I have created elasticsearch pods on w2)

```
root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/opt/bitnami# kubectl get svc -n kube-system
    NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
    coredns                     ClusterIP   10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6d3h
        
root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/opt/bitnami# kubectl exec -it dnsutils sh
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
/ #

/ # nslookup elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data.lilac-efk.svc.cluster.local. 10.233.0.3
Server:         10.233.0.3
Address:        10.233.0.3#53

Name:   elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data.lilac-efk.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.233.49.187
```

I spawned the same dnsutils pod on w5 (.200 subnet) next. nslookup fails on this.

```
root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/opt/bitnami# kubectl exec -it dnsutils sh
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
/ #
/ # ^C
/ # nslookup elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data.lilac-efk.svc.cluster.local 10.233.0.3
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
    
/ # exit
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Logs from nodelocaldns running on w5:

```
 [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data.lilac-efk.lilac-efk.svc.cluster.local. AAAA: dial tcp 10.233.0.3:53: i/o timeout
 [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data.lilac-efk.lilac-efk.svc.cluster.local. A: dial tcp 10.233.0.3:53: i/o timeout
```

From the dnsutils container, I'm not able to reach coredns pod IPs on the other subnet, through overlay network. The cluster is spawned using Calico.

```
 root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/opt/bitnami# kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep coredns
    pod/coredns-dff8fc7d-98mbw                        1/1     Running   3          6d2h    10.233.127.4    saba-k8-vm-m2   <none>           <none>
    pod/coredns-dff8fc7d-cwbhd                        1/1     Running   7          6d2h    10.233.74.7     saba-k8-vm-m1   <none>           <none>
    pod/coredns-dff8fc7d-h4xdd                        1/1     Running   0          2m19s   10.233.82.6     saba-k8-vm-m3   <none>           <none>
        
 root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/opt/bitnami# kubectl exec -it dnsutils sh
 kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
 / # ping 10.233.82.6
 PING 10.233.82.6 (10.233.82.6): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 10.233.82.6: seq=0 ttl=62 time=0.939 ms
 64 bytes from 10.233.82.6: seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.693 ms
 ^C
 --- 10.233.82.6 ping statistics ---
 2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max = 0.693/0.816/0.939 ms
 / # ping 10.233.74.7
 PING 10.233.74.7 (10.233.74.7): 56 data bytes
 ^C
 --- 10.233.74.7 ping statistics ---
 4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
 / # ping 10.233.127.4
 PING 10.233.127.4 (10.233.127.4): 56 data bytes
 ^C
 --- 10.233.127.4 ping statistics ---
 2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

`kube_service_addresses: 10.233.0.0/18 kube_pods_subnet: 10.233.64.0/18`

Because of this behaviour, fluentd running as daemon set on all 5 workers is in CrashLoopBack since it is unable to resolve elasticsearch svc name.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are Calico IPIP links established on each server? `sudo calicoctl.sh node status`. Do you see all those IPs using this command on each server? `ip r | grep tunl` . Are you able to ping those IPs from any server to any server? Do you see any issues in Calico pods log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @[laimison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5689995/laimison) for giving me those pointers.

Posting all my observations, so it can be useful to somebody.

On M1,

```
root@saba-k8-vm-m1:~# ip r | grep tunl
10.233.72.0/24 via 192.168.100.5 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink
10.233.102.0/24 via 192.168.100.4 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink
10.233.110.0/24 via 192.168.100.3 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink
10.233.127.0/24 via 192.168.100.2 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink

root@saba-k8-vm-m1:~# sudo calicoctl.sh node status
Calico process is running.
IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |   SINCE    |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| 192.168.100.2 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established |
| 192.168.200.1 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Passive     |
| 192.168.100.3 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established |
| 192.168.100.4 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established |
| 192.168.100.5 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established |
| 192.168.200.2 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Passive     |
| 192.168.200.3 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Passive     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

On M3,

```
lilac@saba-k8-vm-m3:~$ ip r | grep tunl
10.233.85.0/24 via 192.168.200.3 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink
10.233.98.0/24 via 192.168.200.2 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink

lilac@saba-k8-vm-m3:~$ sudo calicoctl.sh node status
Calico process is running.
IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |   SINCE    |              INFO              |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------------------+
| 192.168.100.1 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|               |                   |       |            | reset by peer                  |
| 192.168.100.2 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|               |                   |       |            | closed                         |
| 192.168.100.3 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|               |                   |       |            | closed                         |
| 192.168.100.4 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|               |                   |       |            | closed                         |
| 192.168.100.5 | node-to-node mesh | start | 2021-04-06 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|               |                   |       |            | closed                         |
| 192.168.200.2 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established                    |
| 192.168.200.3 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-04-06 | Established                    |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------------------+
IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

On M1, 192.168.200.2 and 192.168.200.3 are passive. On M3, I noticed Active Socket: Connection for all .100 IPs. This suggested that M3 is trying to establish a BGP connection, but it is not able to get through.

I was able to `telnet 192.168.100.x 179` from M3.

Checking the calico pod log and node dump from running `/usr/local/bin/calicoctl.sh node diags` on M1, I could see

```
bird: BGP: Unexpected connect from unknown address 10.0.x.x (port 53107)
```

10.0.x.x was the management IP of the server on which .200 VMs were hosted. It was doing a source NAT.

I added this rule:

```
-A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.x.x
```

That solved the issue.

```
root@saba-k8-vm-m1:/tmp/calico050718821/diagnostics/logs# /usr/local/bin/calicoctl.sh node status
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| 192.168.100.2 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:08:38 | Established |
| 192.168.200.1 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:09:15 | Established |
| 192.168.100.3 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:09:24 | Established |
| 192.168.100.4 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:09:02 | Established |
| 192.168.100.5 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:09:47 | Established |
| 192.168.200.2 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:08:55 | Established |
| 192.168.200.3 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 08:09:37 | Established |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

Other things that I tried:

I updated ipipMode across all the nodes. This doesn't solve the issue, but helps improves performance.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/calicoctl.sh patch ippool default-pool -p '{"spec":{"ipipMode": "CrossSubnet"}}'
Successfully patched 1 'IPPool' resource
```

I referred to [calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465963/calico-node-is-not-ready-bird-is-not-ready-bgp-not-established) and set interface=ens3, although this is the only interface on my VMs. Again, doesn't solve the issue, but will help when there are multiple interfaces on the calico node.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue and I could recall setting up some sort of IP Masquerade on the Physical host which is hosting VMs for Kubernetes Master + Worker Nodes. Can you please advise did you add the above iptables Rule on the Physical host or Kubernetes nodes as I dont see any POSTROUTING rules on Physical hosts anymore but there are a few on the Master & Worker nodes which are generated by Kubernetes for calico networking?

Comment: I added the above POSTROUTING rule on the physical host (one that is hosting .200 VMs)